# how to add a string to the end of url with nuxt dynamic routing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

for SEO purposes, I wanna add a string (product title, category title, .... ) to the end of my dynamic route.
my product page structure is like this:

```
pages:

product (folder)
- _id.vue
```

so to show product single page i use the url `example.com/product/1` which `1` is product id.
then in _id.vue page fetch my product:

```js
async fetch(){
    let response = await this.axiosFetch(`product/${this.$route.params.id}`)
    if(this.resOk(response.status)){
        if(this.notEmpty(response.data)){
            this.product = response.data
        }
    }else{
        this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: "not found" })
    }
},
```

now as mentioned above, I wanna add product title at the end of url like `example.com/product/1/nike-shoe`
how can i do this??

**Update**

there is another problem that can't be solved by only params on url:
i have a category page `example.com/category` . on page fetch i fetch cats like this (on page create `catId` is 0 to fetch parents and with each parent i fetch children):

```js
async fetch(){
  let res = await this.$axios.$get(`category/${this.catId})
  this.catArray.push(res)
}
```

i fetch parents, from the parent id ,fetch children and load bellow parent and so on. and all these are in `example.com/category` . no route change only send catId to route query (so i can nav from another page with catId). so how can i add each selected category's title at the end of url and still be in the same page??

Comment: have you tried `this.$route.push`?

Comment: how about `product(folder)->_id(folder)->_slug.vue`?

Comment: @ma_jafari , push will change the route and direct to it, as there is no such page it will gives 404

Comment: @Jazuly , i know what u getting at. send to that page and get the first param in my fetch, right? i prefer other possible options, if there is any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a route with a slugified name of your product and the `id` at the end, and parse the `$route.params.id` to get the `id`.
For that, you will need to use [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify).

Your route will look like:
`example.com/product/${slugifiedProductName}-${id}`

Ex: `example.com/product/nike-shoe-1`

In the file `pages/product/_id.vue` use a regexp to extract `id`.

```js
async fetch(){
    const id = this.$route.params.slug.match(/([0-9])+$/)[0]
    let response = await this.axiosFetch(`product/${id}`)
    if(this.resOk(response.status)){
        if(this.notEmpty(response.data)){
            this.product = response.data
        }
    }else{
        this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: "not found" })
    }
},
```

Note: if you use UUID, the regexp is `[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$`

Comment: tanx a lot . for product i coded with two param and fetched the first. `/product/_id/_slug` . but i have another problem that is a bit more complicated! i updated my question with new one.

Answer (score 1):

In nuxt3, things are easier, setup your route like this: pages/product/[id]/[category]/index.vue

then on a button or anything clickable add:

```
<button @click="$router.push(`/product/${props.id}/${props.category}`)">View Porduct</button>
```

then catch that id or category with:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ $route.params.id}} , {{ $route.params.category}}</div>
</template>
```

or in the scripts with:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const route = useRoute()
  const { id } = route.params()
  const { category } = route.params()  
</script>
```